# TypeORM: Delete a unique column in entity?

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I have an `Entity`:

```
@Entity()
export class SomeEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  @Generated("increment")
  id_tmp: number;
}
```

For some reason, I want to delete `id_tmp`.

I try to delete the `id_tmp` in entity, or try to delete step by step like remove `unique`, remove `@Generated("increment")`... But I always get error:

`Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

How can I do that?